# Mostrar Resultados de Query En

Tags: php, sql

Hago una consulta a mysqli de publicaciones completas, es decir con sus respectivas columnas, (Titulo / Descripcion/ Precio / Imagenes / Etc.), y muestro todo armado en un div. Hasta ahi todo bien, si la consulta arroja una publicacion la muestra correctamente, si la consulta arroja varios resultados, tambien los muestra correctamente, salvo que las ordena un div encima de otro (en forma vertical), y yo queria saber si hay alguna forma de mostrar los resultados uno al lado del otro hasta ocupar el ancho de la pantalla en dos o tres divs, y que continúe abajo con los demas resultados de la misma forma.
Desd Ya gracias por leer y compartir sus ideas.

```html
 echo("<center><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>  
            <scrypt type text/javascript</scrypt>
            
                <div class=contenedor>
                    <div class=publicacion>
                       <div>$row[titulo]</div>
                       <div>  $ $row[precio]</div>
                       <div>  * Publicado Por : $row[vendedor]  *                          </div>
                       <div> Categoría : $row[categoria]</div>
                       <div class=imagenPrincipal>
                            <a href=$imagen1><img class=imgp                                         src=$imagen1></a>
                            </div> 
                    
                    <div class=miniaturas>
                        <div class=flex>
                             <a href=$imagen2><img class=img                                          src=$imagen2></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class=flex>
                             <a href=$imagen3><img class=img                                          src=$imagen3></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class=flex>
                             <a href=$imagen4><img class=img                                          src=$imagen4></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    
                     <div class=descripcion>$row[descripcion]</div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            
        </center>
```

Comment: Otra ves no me salio el saludo XD Hola a Todos

Comment: En tu pregunta solo veo un div... ¿donde se supone que iran los otros? ¿dentro del de la clase contenedor o tambien seran contenedor? Supongo que poniendo un estilo `float:left` de momento te bastaría

Comment: Hola Master Como Va, El Div es uno solo, y se replica de acuerdo a la cantidad de resultados, pero los visualiza uno sobre otro, yo queria saber como puede hacerse para que muestre uno al costado de otro hasta cubrir el ancho de la pantalla y que de haber mas, continúe abajo de la misma manera.

Comment: Porque la cantidad de resutados son aleatorios, es decir puede haber uno, ninguno o 1000, dependiendo de las cantidades publicadas dentro de la misma categoria, se entiende?

Comment: pruebo lo de float-left y te comento. gracias.

Comment: Se entiende perfectamente, ya lo decias en la pregunta.  Pero yo te pregunto cual de ellos se repite, si el de la clase contenedor o el de dentro. Sea cual sea empieza agregando `style="float:left;"` en el a ver que pasa.

Comment: Por cierto, quita esto -> `<scrypt type text/javascript</scrypt>` por favor, no hace nada, no existe esa etiqueta, no la cierras bien, y puede estropear todo lo que venga despues

Comment: Lo de float:left Funcionó. Gracias.